# Trouble with retrieving only values from an Excel file using load_workbook() in Python

Tags: python, excel, load, return-value

On Python,  I use:

```
 wbin = load_workbook(filein, data_only=True)
```

Since in the `filein` there are some functions and I need the value, but the option `data_only=True` doesn't work.

Some cells contains functions example:'=MIN(BN120:BN122)' but I want read the value = 10 and not the function.

On how can get only the value?

The scrip doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you can try this to read the calculated values of cells that contain formulas in an Excel file using the openpyxl lib:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

def read_excel_with_formulas(filename):
    workbook = load_workbook(filename, data_only=True)
    worksheet = workbook.active

    for row in worksheet.iter_rows(values_only=True):
        for cell in row:
            if cell is not None and cell.startswith('='):
                column_letter = get_column_letter(cell.column)
                cell.value = worksheet[column_letter + str(cell.row)].value

    workbook.save("updated_" + filename)

# Example usage
filein = "your_file.xlsx"
read_excel_with_formulas(filein)
```

`load_workbook()` load the Excel file with `data_only=True` option, to load the calculated values instead of formulas.

`iter_rows()` and `values_only=True` to iterate over each cell in the worksheet